# How to create Google Maps API Marker with device's geolocation (after its async callback)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous, google-maps-markers

Please help. Trying to create a map of Chicago, and have my current known location appear as a marker on that map. The problem is (though I can find no explicit mention of this in any tutorial or doc), it seems I have to declare the `marker` var in the same scope as (perhaps right after?) I declare the map---global variables don't seem to work. This is difficult, since I'm making an asynchronous call, and thus only have a verified `position` for my marker in the callback function I've defined. Thus the following code doesn't work...

```
(function() {

  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.87811, -87.62980);
  var info = document.getElementById("info");
  var map;

  function showError(error) 
  {
    info.innerHTML += "Error: " + error.message;
  }

  function getLocation(position) 
  { 
    current_location = new google.maps.LatLng(
      position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: current_location,
      map: map
    });
  }

  window.onload = function() {

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: chicago,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    if (navigator.geolocation) 
    {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, showError);
    }
  } 

})();
```

I can see no clean way out of this, but would love to be shown otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, than this should work, this is how I handle the asynchronous creation of the marker at the found position in my own app, and it works great! If this isn't what you meant then let me know!

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
        }
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmaps'), mapOptions);
    locateMe();


}


function locateMe() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            map.setZoom(15);
            setMarkerPosition(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            updateLocation();
        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        });
    } else {
    }
}


function setMarkerPosition(lati, longi) {
    var latLongMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(lati,longi);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLongMarker,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        title: "Your Location"
    });
}
```

Comment: I copied everything that looked like it could affect anything into my own example and was able to get it to work, I think, though! Thank you!

Comment: The solution, I guess, is to make `marker` one of those implicit global variables, by not declaring it--which is what you did in your example, and when I did exactly that it works.